# Dealing a multidimensional array and trying to concatenate as desired efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

**What we have:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[11,22],[111,222],[1111,2222]])
b = np.array([[3],[33],[333],[3333]])
c = np.array([[4,5,6],[44,55,66],[444,555,666],[4444,5555,6666]])


data = [a,b,c]
```

**What we want:**

```
[[   1    2    3    4    5    6]
 [  11   22   33   44   55   66]
 [ 111  222  333  444  555  666]
 [1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666]]
```

**Code to perform task as required:**

```
new_arr=[]
for i in range(data[0].shape[0]):
  index = []
  for j in range(len(data)):
    index.extend(data[j][i])
  new_arr.append(index)
new_data = np.array(new_arr)
print(new_data)
```

**Note:** The solution is correct and gets the output as desired, but is there any other way to do it which is more efficient (faster)?

**Question:** I am performing a machine learning task and training a model needs to go through these loops a lot many times, making the training process very slow. Is there any way we can have a more efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) is what you are after.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[11,22],[111,222],[1111,2222]])
b = np.array([[3],[33],[333],[3333]])
c = np.array([[4,5,6],[44,55,66],[444,555,666],[4444,5555,6666]])

d = np.hstack([a, b, c])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[[   1    2    3    4    5    6]
 [  11   22   33   44   55   66]
 [ 111  222  333  444  555  666]
 [1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666]]
```

Comment: I edited the code to make the actual answer more obvious - hope you don't mind :)

Comment: What I had was a fully runnable example.  I think you should have left it that way.

Comment: Okay @TimRoberts. My rationale was that it can look like your solution has more code than it actually _does_. Maybe you could separate the key code into a new code block. Because it kinda looks like your solution has 5 or 6 lines though it only has 1...but it's yours, so you can do what you want :)

Comment: I want someone to be able to cut-and-paste from the answer directly, and produce exactly the output I got.  I think that's an important attribute.  I've certainly cursed the questions that don't follow that guideline.  Even this one did not import numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with `axis=1`

```
new_arr = np.concatenate([a, b, c], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_arr
array([[   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6],
       [  11,   22,   33,   44,   55,   66],
       [ 111,  222,  333,  444,  555,  666],
       [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666]])
```

Comment: That's cute, and I'll remember it, but I think it's clear the performance won't be as good.

Comment: You're right, but it might be better than the OP's code :) At least it looks nicer ;)

Comment: `np.hstack` is `np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)`.  Your `np.append` is `np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)`.  Same thing but it only takes 2 arrays at a time.  I nearly always recommends collecting the arrays in a list, and doing the `concatenate` just once.

Comment: Ha! I tried doing `np.con<TAB>` in my IPython but nothing came up. Now I see it _does exist_, so maybe I should've been a little more patient :D